# What Causes the Numeric Overflow in this PL/SQL Function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, overflow, numeric

I can run this command on Oracle 10.2 without problem:

```
SQL> select instr(unistr('foo'), chr(4050596145)) as hazit from dual;

     HAZIT
----------
     0
```

So I tried to encapsulate it into a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hazit(string IN VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN instr(unistr(string), chr(4050596145));
END;
/

Function created.
```

But I get a numeric overflow error when I try to use it:

```
SQL> select hazit('foo') FROM DUAL;
select hazit('foo') FROM DUAL
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
ORA-06512: at "DWHEELER.HAZIT", line 4
```

What gives?

Comment: A guess , chr(4050596145) won't fit in a signed integer in whatever the charset of your database is. Widen the return type of the function.

Comment: strange, because this works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c163a/1

Comment: I somehow feel that this is happening due to `chr(4050596145)` because if you replace it with a random string `'abcdefghijkl'` it works just fine.

Comment: @A.B.Cade Your solution works for me, too. Care to put it into an answer that I can then accept?

Comment: @Annjawn Yes, it works if I use `chr(1234)`.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson My function is returning the result of `instr()`, which is not going to be anything other than a regular integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an explanation but this seems to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hazit(string IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
i number;
BEGIN
    select instr(unistr(string), chr(4050596145))
      into i from dual;
    return i;
END;
/
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c163a/1) is a fiddle

Comment: Thanks @A.B.Cade. I actually pasted in the literal character instead of using `chr()` to get around the problem. It's a bizarre one, though, I gotta say.

Comment: @theory, I found something about a different function (`rawtohex`) which behaves differently in sql and plsql (see here http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rawtohex.php) perhaps the same happens to `chr()` function as it also makes implict conversions (http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/functions018.htm)

Comment: Dude, that's just *whack!* Oracle continues to annoy…